# fclose(stdout) causes a crash when using freopen even after NULL check

Tags: c, fclose, freopen

I am trying to print stdout to file using freopen and the code below crashes. I am NULL checking and I'm fairly sure I don't have a segmentation fault somewhere else in the program since I verified that all my mallocs are correct.

The program crashes when it reaches the `fclose(stdout)` and doesn't print the error messgage I attached to check it. The `printf("\nTestBeforeClose");` line prints but the `printf("\nTestAfterClose");` does not.

```
int printAllVarRedir(char * filename, int redirmarker) {
    var *current = NULL;

    if (redirmarker == 1) {
        if (freopen(filename, "w", stdout) == NULL) {
            perror("Unable to open file");
            return 1;
        } else {
            if (head == NULL) {
                perror("No Variables");
                fclose(stdout);
                return 1;
            } else {
                current = head;
                printf("%s=%s. Address is %p.Next is:%p\n", current->varname, current->value, current, current->next);
                while (current->next != NULL) {
                    current = current->next;
                    printf("%s=%s. Address is %p.Next is:%p\n", current->varname, current->value, current,
                           current->next);
                }
                printf("\nTestBeforeClose");
                if (fclose(stdout) == EOF) {
                    printf("\nError is %s\n", strerror(errno));
                }
                printf("\nTestAfterClose\n");
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the var struct I am using:

```
typedef struct varlist{
    char * varname;
    char * value;
    struct varlist * next;
}var;

var * head = NULL;
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to step through what is happening and/or get a trace back from the point of the crash? If not, please learn this essential skill, which will help you understand your code, and save your and others' time by letting you solve your own problems instead of asking the internet.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem so we can run the code ourselves. If the linked list code isn't directly related, leave it out. Creating a MCVE may help you identify the issue.

Comment: @JohnKugelman when I made a MCVE just trying to use freopen, print something and fclose(stdout) it works. It's when I use this function and the linked list that it does not work.

Comment: How many times do you call your `printAllVarRedir()` function before it crashes?  Because once you call that code, your `stdout` is closed for good.

Comment: If you close `stdout`, where do you expect `TestAfterClose` to appear?

Comment: Why are you redirecting `stdout` anyway? Why not just use `fprintf()`?

Comment: @RobK I'm making a simple unix shell and I need to make a system which redirects output to a file from a selection of functions which don't contain fprintf().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course `printf("\nTestAfterClose\n");` doesn't print. `printf` prints to `stdout` which you've just closed.

Comment: Thanks! Solved by changing the code to use dup instead of freopen